# Only display unique values within underscore loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am displaying product ids from a json file, for each look, using an underscore loop. I want to make sure no repeated ids are included in the loop, how can I do this?

**JS (underscore)**

```
  <% _.each( listItem.products, function( product, index ){ %>                                                                           
          <li class="tab-link productTile tab-<%= index + 1 %>" data-tab-id="<%= index + 1 %>" data-product-pid-thumb="<%= product %>"></li>
    <% }) %>
```

**JSON**

```
looks = [{
        "id": "look1",
        "products": ["hbeu50271385", "hbeu50274296", "hbeu50272359", "hbeu50272802", "hbeu50272802", "hbeu50272802", "hbeu50272802"]
    }, {
        "id": "look2",
        "products": [
            "hbeu50274106", "hbeu50273647", "hbeu50274754", "hbeu50274063", "hbeu50274911", "hbeu50274106", "hbeu50240022", "hbeu50271944"
        ]
    }, {
        "id": "look3",
        "products": [
            "hbeu50272935", "hbeu50274426", "hbeu50271624", "hbeu50274762", "hbeu50275366", "hbeu50274433", "hbeu50262002", "hbeu50272364", "hbeu50272359"
        ]
    }
    .......
]
```

Comment: You could use [_.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) method

Answer (score 0):

You can use _uniq method like this:

```
var looks = [{id:1}, {id:1}, {id:2}];

var uniqProducts = _.uniq(looks, function(l) {
  return l.id;
});
```

Then change to this var in your loop:

```
 <% _.each( uniqProducts, function( product, index ){ %>                                                                           
  <li class="tab-link productTile tab-<%= index + 1 %>" data-tab-id="<%= index + 1 %>" data-product-pid-thumb="<%= product %>"></li>
 <% }) %>
```